LaTeX Error: File `ERD.tex (ERD Diagram)' not found
I am trying to compile a file that I have created, but am receiving the following error in OverLeaf:
The compiler cannot find the file you want to include. Make sure that you have uploaded the file and specified the file location correctly.
Learn more
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex (ERD Diagram))

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.24 \input{ERD.tex (ERD Diagram)}
                                            % Include ERD Diagram^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

What does cannot /read from terminal in nonstop modes mean, and how can I resolve it?
A minimally reproducible document can be found below:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For generating dummy text
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric, arrows}

\title{Bask-it: Technical and User Documentation}
\author{Your Name or Your Company}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\input{Introduction}        % Include Introduction
\input{ System_Overview}     % Include System Overview
\input{Technical_Documentation} % Include Technical Documentation
\input{ERD.tex (ERD Diagram)}          % Include ERD Diagram
\input{appendix}            % Include Appendix

\end{document}


assuming that your file is called ERD.tex you should use \input{ERD} and not \input{ERD.tex (ERD Diagram)}.

I have renamed the file as ERD.tex. Why do you this renaming the file as ERD is better?

ERD.tex is fine, but you then can use \input{ERD}. TeX will add the extension.
